# Incompatible types when assigning to type char[32] from type 'char*'

Tags: c

I'm trying to set the parameters of the structure below:

```
typedef struct thread_args_s {
    int idx;
    int role;
    int fifo_desc;
    char client_fifo_name[FIFO_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
    char msg[MSG_MAX_LENGTH];
} thread_args_t;
```

I've a problem assigning `thread_args_t->client_fifo_name`.

The client_fifo_name is given by a concatenation of the strings `CLIENT_FIFO_NAME_SUFFIX + i`, using `sprintf()`.

In detail:

```
int i;
char* name;

for(i=0; i<THREAD_COUNT-1; i++){
    thread_args_t* prod_args = malloc(sizeof(thread_args_t));
    prod_args->idx = i;
    prod_args->role = PROD_ROLE;
    prod_args-> fifo_desc = server_fifo;
    sprintf(name, "%s%d", CLIENT_FIFO_NAME_SUFFIX, i);
    //How to assign the string "name" to prod_args->client_fifo_name?
    prod_args->client_fifo_name = name;
    [...]}
```

Compiling, the error is:

> Incompatible types when assigning to type `char[32]` from type `char*`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: `name` is just a pointer - where is the memory where we will store something?

Comment: `client_fifo_name` is an array, you cannot assign a pointer to an array. If you want to copy the contents pointed to by the array (in this case a string), you have to use `strncpy`.

Comment: Why not just use `prod_args->client_fifo_name` in the `sprintf`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp you're right!!

Answer (score 2):

The types are incompatible because the left hand of the assignment is to exactly 32 characters, but the right hand of the assignment is a pointer.  I'm guessing, but you probably want:

```
snprintf(prod_args->client_fifo_name,
         FIFO_NAME_MAX_LENGTH,
         "%s%d",
         CLIENT_FIFO_NAME_SUFFIX, i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use `name` would be (here you have not allocated any memory to which the `char*` variable points to)

- `char *name = malloc(MAXLEN+1);` Check the return value of `malloc`.

Or using an array

- `char name[MAXLEN+1];`

After you did that - you will have to use `strcpy` to copy the content of the `name` to the designated array. Arrays are non-modifiable lvalue - assigning something to - it is error.

So after you make sure that destination has enough storage to store the string you are going to copy write

```
strcpy(prod_args->client_fifo_name , name);
```

To explain the error - here it finds the type mismatch in the line `prod_args->client_fifo_name = name;` here the left hand of assignment has type `char []` and on the right it is `char *`. These mismatch of type in the assignment causes the error.

Also I just corrected the possible errors - you can omit allocating extra memory before copying to the actual one. You can directly use `s(*)printf` with the final target variable as buffer.

Comment: @P.P..: You can't assign to `char[]` - that's the idea, I will edit it

Comment: @P.P..: Edited.

Answer (score 0):

> Incompatible types when assigning to type char[32] from type 'char*'
>   I've a problem assigning thread_args_t->client_fifo_name.

As `prod_args->client_fifo_name` in an *array*, it can not be *assigned* in C.

To assign a chracter array's elements, code may copy data with `sprintf(), snprintf(), memcpy(), strcpy()` or the like as answered by [@Whilom Chime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48794344/2410359).

Code could assign each element of the array (a `char`) one at a time too, but let us avoid that.

`snprintf()` is a good choice, yet robust good also checks to see if data fits.

```
// sprintf(name, "%s%d", CLIENT_FIFO_NAME_SUFFIX, i);
// prod_args->client_fifo_name = name;
int count = snprintf(prod_args->client_fifo_name, sizeof prod_args->client_fifo_name,  
    "%s%d", CLIENT_FIFO_NAME_SUFFIX, i);

// Check for success
if (count < 0 || count >= sizeof prod_args->client_fifo_name) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Not enough room or other error.  Good-bye\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```